# Mysql function error to SUM

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, SUM(amount)
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN payment
ON customer.customer_id=payment.amount
ORDER BY amount DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

**I get error:**

> #1140 - In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'sakila_tak14.customer.first_name'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Add a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: The join is suspicious too: payment.customer_id or such I would have thought.

Answer (score 1):

V5.7.5 & up versions of MySQL implement a stricter use of aggregate functions & non-aggregated columns are not allowed in the select list & ORDER BY list (or HAVING clause). See : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Also you cant order by the amount column & get your expected order (if you take the setting ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to false option) - as you have summed it & the resulting column will no longer be called amount - you need to use an alias.

You will either need to group by the first & last names :

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, SUM(amount) summedammount
FROM customer LEFT JOIN payment
ON customer.customer_id=payment.amount
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
ORDER BY summedammount DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

set the system variable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY to false, or use the ANY_VALUE function :

```
SELECT ANY_VALUE(first_name), ANY_VALUE(last_name), SUM(amount) summedammount
FROM customer
LEFT JOIN payment
ON customer.customer_id=payment.amount
ORDER BY summedammount DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: Identification of this feature/change in 5.7.5 and up is good to know!  Nice to see the extended Group By clause in earlier versions of MySQL is being  revisited.

Answer (score 0):

You've made amount an aggregate, so you need to group all of the non-aggregate fields. Try this:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, SUM(amount)
FROM customer LEFT JOIN payment
ON customer.customer_id=payment.amount
GROUP BY first_name, last_name
ORDER BY amount DESC LIMIT 10;
```

Comment: `GROUP BY` should be before `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Ullas Thanks. I fixed it.